# TempData not kept between postback

Tags: model-view-controller, tempdata

I need some advice on how to proceed with the mvc app I'm building. On my page I type out who is logged in to the page. This I first did by creating a base class where I created a user class which contained the users name and a image representing the user. Then I passed this class on to my views. But I also need to pass other models to my views depending on what view I'm in. Sure I could build a class that contain all different models I need to use on each page but there should be a easy way to pass name and image values across the pages and be persistant? I tried TempData together with TempData.Keep() but that was not persistant. How can I pass theses values between pages?

```
    public ActionResult Validate(AccountModels.LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                var mu = _repo.GetUser(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                TempData["Name"] = mu.Name;
                TempData["Image"] = mu.Image;
                TempData.Keep();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            }

        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jyoti said, you could use of **Keep()** method.

To make it easy to work with **TempData**, I wrote these methods in my BaseController, and I use it in every controller when I need to transfer data between actions or between view and controller.

```
    protected TReturnType GetTempDataValue<TReturnType>(PsmConstants.TempDataKey sessionName, bool peekData =false )
    { 
        object value = peekData ? TempData.Peek(sessionName.ToString()) : TempData[sessionName.ToString()];

        return (TReturnType) value;
    }

    protected void RemoveTempData(PsmConstants.TempDataKey sessionName)
    { 
        if (TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()) && TempData[sessionName.ToString()] == null) return;
        TempData[sessionName.ToString()] = null;
    }

    protected void SetTempDataValue(PsmConstants.TempDataKey sessionName, object value)
    { 
        if(TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()))
            TempData[sessionName.ToString()]=null;

        TempData[sessionName.ToString()] = value;
    }

    protected void KeepTempDataValue(PsmConstants.TempDataKey sessionName)
    {
        if (TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()))
            TempData.Keep(sessionName.ToString());
    }
```

And this is the Keys enumeration :

```
 public enum TempDataKey
    {

        PageError = 1,
        PageInfo = 2
    }
```

And this is, the usage of these methods(Set value and Get value from TempData):

```
SetTempDataValue(PsmConstants.TempDataKey.PageError , 'your error message' );

var originalValues = GetTempDataValue<MyModel>(PsmConstants.TempDataKey.Info, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use session instead of Temp if it is not working.but i think it should work.
TempData["Name"] = mu.Name;TempData["Image"] = mu.Image;TempData.Keep();
How you are passing this into other models,Please share the source code so that it will easy to identify.

Comment: I just declare it like above in the login controller, isn't it supposed to be available in all views after that

Comment: Code is shared in the original post. I thought that it was enough to set a Tempdata value in one page or a basecontroller and that it would then be available on every page much like a session variable.